# Entangled text boxes

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, textbox

A mere Windows textbox greatly surprised me today.

I have two unrelated text boxes inside an application. I can type in either text box and switch the focus by clicking on them. Then happens some event X, which I can't describe here for reasons given below. After this event happens, the two text boxes become "entangled" in an almost quantum way.

Say, text box A was focused before X happened. When I click text box B to type in some text, the new text appears in text box A, whereas the blinking cursor happily moves along in text box B through the void, as if the text were there.

No amount of clicking on either text boxes can resolve this. The cursor will always remain in B, whereas the text will always go to A.

Message spying reveals that after the event X, the text boxes lose the ability to lose or gain focus. When I click on B, WM_LOSE_FOCUS does not come to A, and WM_SET_FOCUS does not come to B. (The rectangles and visibility of the boxes are OK.)

The same thing happens in Windows XP and Windows 7.

Now, event X: it's a big event in a third-party UI library which I cannot reverse-engineer in a timely manner. (Namely, docking a pane in wxAUI.)

I am sure that this behavior is the result of incorrect WinAPI calls to the text boxes (garbage in - garbage out). I would like to know what could possibly cause such "textbox trip" to know where to start looking for the bug.

Thanks!

Comment: A couple things: First, have you update to their latest version?  Second, can you reproduce the behavior in a small test app?  Third, do you have any events hooked up by the two textboxes?

Comment: Chris, updating to the latest version of wxWidgets will break binary compatibility with existing plugins (my application is already "in the wild"), so it can't be the final solution, at least for this relatively minor problem. I will try to reconstruct the problem in a minimal app if there are no quick hints from WinAPI pros. There are no events hooked up by the text boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. It was me. There was a silly bug in focus management. It caused the focus to be rapidly (immediately) transferred to text box B and then back to text box A immediately after "event X". And though it only happened once, it was enough to wreak havoc in the textboxes till the end of their lives.

Why the special effects? It turns out that Windows hates two *rapid consecutive* manipulations with UI elements. I once had a similarly weird bug when I tried to move a control by setting its origin and its size in two different steps. The control would behave very randomly after this. Only when I moved it properly - in one step - the weirdness stopped.

Thanks for your attention and sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty strange one, and without being able to look at some code the best I can do is an educated guess.

It sounds to me like the UI library is handling notifications (key down, focus, etc.) for text box B and acting on them as though they were meant for text box A. Like there's a variable like `activeTextBox` that holds the handle of text box A, even when it should be pointing to text box B.

Whereas I can imagine a UI library bug causing this kind of behavior, I would think it's much more likely that client code would cause it. Have you ruled out your code as the culprit?

Comment: Jim, the UI library doesn't know anything about the text boxes. It manages the distant grandparents of the text boxes (it implements a tabbed interface, where the texboxes are inside two different tabs). I use the textboxes in a very straightforward way like everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Do the text boxes have unique identifiers?

did you tie their messages and message handlers up correctly?

In particular, it sounds like the control that has event X might have sub-control identifiers which clash with your control identifiers.

if the problem is reproducible, then I would make a small test example and send it to the control's vendor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Identifier clash is indeed one possible reason that I will investigate.